# Insert BoundField into DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, hide, code-behind, detailsview

Basically I have a detailsview, dependent on what query it is I have certain BoundFields I'd like to show or hide.

Using visual basic, I know that I can use .visible = false. That does the trick, however, it sacrifices my alternating row style in the process.

Any ideas?

Thanks

By the way if you write it in C# I will probably understand.

Comment: Please show us the code where you are changing the BoundField's visibility.

Comment: If the detailsview row to hide it row 2.. 

DetailsView1.Rows(2).Visible = False

Comment: there is no property called Rows on a DetailsView

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create several asp:panel objects.  Inside each panel object, put a single DetailsView.  In your codebehind, you will want to show the panel that contains the proper DetailsView for your query, and hide the rest of the panels.